# SignalR Not Capturing Reconnecting Events on Client Side

Tags: javascript, signalr

Here is my javascript code trying to intercept the events. Very simple and straight forward.

```
        $.connection.hub.reconnecting = function (cb) {
            $('#hub-info').text(getDateTime() + ': reconnecting... '); //breakpoint
            if(cb) cb();
        };
        $.connection.hub.reconnected = function (cb) {
            $('#hub-info').text(getDateTime() + ': reconnected '); //breakpoint
            if(cb) cb();
        };
        $.connection.hub.disconnected = function (cb) {
            $('#hub-info').text(getDateTime() + ': disconnected '); //breakpoint
            if(cb) cb();
        };
        $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            //...
         });
```

Hub `start()` correctly, no problem. However, when the connection is lost, break points are not hit, none of these functions are fired. I know signalR is working because I get the following output from console (Chrome Debugger).

```
[19:21:02] SignalR: Keep alive has been missed, connection may be dead/slow. jquery.signalR.js:84 
[19:21:08] SignalR: Keep alive timed out.  Notifying transport that connection has been lost. jquery.signalR.js:84 
[19:21:10] SignalR: Closing the Websocket. jquery.signalR.js:84 
[19:21:10] SignalR: webSockets reconnecting. query.signalR.js:84 
[19:21:10] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost/sr/reconnect?
```

What have I done wrong? Thanks for the help :)

SignalR version (2.2.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you might need to use the events as functions, passing in a callback, instead of doing assignment. https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#connectionlifetime

```
$.connection.hub.reconnecting(function () {
  $('#hub-info').text(getDateTime() + ': reconnecting... ');
});
```